# How can I build an automated water valve for a coffee maker?

Tags: water, valve

Our home has a remodeled kitchen and we have yet to install a backsplash.  Before we do I was wondering if I couldn't add some functionality.
We currently have a simple coffee maker sitting on our counter.  Not that it's a huge pain, but it would be nice to run a water line up to it from the basement and add a valve so that we could easily fill the coffee maker with water without pulling it out and using the pitcher.
I'm thinking the same kind of water line that we use for our ice maker.

As a simple project I would like a simple push button valve (one that could not be left on and forgotten).  Lowe's/Home Depot have turn valves that could be left on to overflow the kitchen.

As a more advanced option I would like a valve where I could set the number of cups I want and it would automatically shut off when I reached the correct amount.

Does anyone know where I might be able to come across either kind of a valve?

Comment: "Shop for me" questions are considered off-topic.

Comment: Aren't "shop for me" more related to off-the-shelf?  This is not a common gizmo at a big box store.

Comment: @HerrBag: Agreed, these are not common gizmos I'm looking for.    I have searched all the big box stores and many other websites.  I know what I want in general, but I don't really know what I need.  Which makes it hard to even shop for it.  I'm looking for someone who has worked with these kinds of valves and can provide more insight.

Comment: If the actual question is "Does anyone know where I might be able to come across either kind of a valve?" then really all you're asking for is the name of a supplier.

Comment: Just a word of caution to make sure any valve and fittings you use are appropriate for residential water pressure, which can be over 100 psi under certain circumstances. A valve that bursts in the middle of the night could cause a lot of damage very quickly.

Comment: @Steven You may be partially correct, but 50% of the battle of finding things online is knowing what they actually called.  I could probably find them if I knew exactly what I was looking for...which I don't yet. Maybe if I found supplier with a easy to search website I might be able to answer my own question.  However, I'm not trying to turn this into a "Shop for me" question.

Answer (score 3):

If you're not married to your specific existing coffee pot you can purchase coffee machines which are designed to take in a water supply line.

Comment: Married to my wife, not the coffee maker.  Not looking to replace either at this time ;)  Thanks for the response though!

Answer (score 0):

A recent flood prevention project for an upstairs laundry included a 12v solenoid operated ball valve.  Look for a dishwasher floodstop type product, which would satisfy your push button solution

Higher levels of automation would start with an open loop control based on a timer. Open loop systems are very sensitive to pressure and flow changes, which would affect accuracy.

A closed loop system would need to measure flow or sense level, to gather feedback on the status of the fill.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas.  I guess I was looking for an even simpler option for the push button valve.  I would be fine with a mechanical valve that the user holds open and upon releasing it, the valve closes automatically.  I think I'm missing some kind of technical term, because my searches are too vague.

Answer (score 0):

a pneumatic " Push to Exit " button will work perfectly. We use them in the city where mechanical time delay is required by code with certain hardware configs.